# how to find average prices from one array by crossing it to last 30 days from other array? javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have these 2 arrays ,
one contains the time period, the second one contains the prices for each period.

how can I output the average price for the last 30 days, 60 days, etc...?

```
time[
'2021-01-14', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-16',
'2021-02-16', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-22',
'2021-02-26', '2021-02-28', '2021-04-07',
'2021-04-25', '2021-04-26', '2021-05-10',
'2021-05-11', '2021-05-13', '2021-05-15',
'2021-05-16', '2021-05-24', '2021-06-09',
'2021-06-14', '2021-06-14', '2021-06-17',
'2021-06-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-07-15',
'2021-07-17', '2021-07-17', '2021-07-19',
'2021-07-19', '2021-08-02'
]
prices[
 79999, 69999, 76641, 76506, 79999,
 69999, 64999, 69999, 79999, 72500,
 69999, 72500, 77449, 77433, 77684,
 79999, 69999, 79999, 69999,    -1,
 69999,    -1, 69999, 74999, 69999,
 74999, 69999, 74999, 64999
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need help for your approach?

Comment: maybe combine both into a map instead? have the date as a key and an array of prices as values (maybe skip -1?). this way you don't need to keep track of the range that covers the last x days.

Comment: well the original array I'm getting is from an API request, which contains in one array - the time (in milliseconds) and right below its price - [time1,price1,time2,price2,time3,price3]
 
I have succeeded to separate it into 2 different arrays - 1 contains the time and one contains the dates. 

So far I have no idea how to output the last 30 days and match it to the prices array.  
I'm trying to find a solution together here...

Comment: If you could make the API return an array of objects that would make more sense, like: [{"date": "2021-01-14", "price": 79999}, {...}, {...}]. Then you keep the relationship between date and price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I combine the two arrays using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and make the time into a Data object. I create a Date object and reduce it by 30 days. I filter the combined array using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and calculate the sum of the prices using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
var time = [
'2021-01-14', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-16',
'2021-02-16', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-22',
'2021-02-26', '2021-02-28', '2021-04-07',
'2021-04-25', '2021-04-26', '2021-05-10',
'2021-05-11', '2021-05-13', '2021-05-15',
'2021-05-16', '2021-05-24', '2021-06-09',
'2021-06-14', '2021-06-14', '2021-06-17',
'2021-06-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-07-15',
'2021-07-17', '2021-07-17', '2021-07-19',
'2021-07-19', '2021-08-02'
];
var prices = [
 79999, 69999, 76641, 76506, 79999,
 69999, 64999, 69999, 79999, 72500,
 69999, 72500, 77449, 77433, 77684,
 79999, 69999, 79999, 69999,    -1,
 69999,    -1, 69999, 74999, 69999,
 74999, 69999, 74999, 64999
];

var combined = time.map((d,i) => {return {date: new Date(d), price: prices[i]}});

//var d = new Date();
// for the purpose of this fixed set of date/price this code will have a fixed "now"-date instead of a future date:
var d = new Date('2021-08-04');
d.setDate(d.getDate()-30);

var filtered = combined.filter(item => item.date.getTime() > d.getTime());

console.log('Should return 6 objects when d = 2021-08-04:', filtered.length);

var priceSum = filtered.reduce((accumulator, item) => {return accumulator + item.price}, 0);

console.log('Should return 429994:', priceSum);
```

You can adjust the time range by defining another date object from a fixed date, like:

```js
var d = new Date('2021-08-01');
console.log(d);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-60);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
for some reason I'm getting 0 console.log(priceSum);
am I missing something ?

Comment: @Timmy OK, can you either "copy the snippet to answer" and try to debug the code as if you where to answer or copy the code, so that you can test it locally? Maybe in any case I should rewrite the code to a fixed date so that it will always select the latest entries.

Comment: Hey, I have reviewed your code again, you are definitely right! although I succeed to solved it in a different way - I took inspiration from your code. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average of the last 15 values from the `prices` array:

```js
prices.slice(-15).reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / 15;
```

Explanation:

- `prices.slice(-15)` creates an array containing the last 15 values of the `prices` array
- `.reduce((a, b) => (a + b))` returns the sum of these values
- You divide by 15 to get the average.

N.B: the `-1` values will mess with the result

Comment: Thank you i'll try that right now .. it seems like a good option I can use. 
the -1 referring to a period in which the item might be out of stock so it cant send data for that period. - I will have to ignore it some how

Answer (score 0):

Get the N last price you want to get the average with slice

Sum their values with reduce

```
function averagePrice(lastDayCount){

      if (lastDayCount <= prices.length){

         let lastPrices = prices.slice(prices.length - lastDayCount); 
        
         const totalPrice= lastPrices.reduce(function(subtotal, p) {
             const tmp= subtotal+ p;
             return tmp;
         }, 0);  

         return totalPrice / lastDayCount;

      }
      return 0;
    
}
```